# Stop window scroll when an image with active link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making this gallery images with small thumbnails below the big image, when i try to click the thumbnails below, the window automatically scrolls up the top page, is there a way to disable the window scroll when an image with a link is clicked?  this is a sample of my code:

```
<div class="image-gallery">
        <div class="big-image">   
            <img id="10" src="images/pr10.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" />
            <img id="11" src="images/pr11.jpg" width="250px" height="250px" />
            <img id="12" src="images/pr12.jpg" width="250px" height="250px"/>
            <img id="13" src="images/pr13.jpg" width="250px" height="250px"/>
            <img id="default" src="images/pr10.jpg" width="250px" height="250px"/>
        </div>
<!--thumbnails-->
        <ul style="text-align:center">
        <li><a href="#10"><img  src="images/pr10.jpg" width="30" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#11"><img  src="images/pr11.jpg" width="30" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#12"><img  src="images/pr12.jpg" width="30" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#13"><img  src="images`enter code here`/pr13.jpg" width="30" /></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Add event.preventDefault(); to the anchor tag click event :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski thanks but not the solution i was looking for =(

Comment: Its default behaviour `<a href="#10">` linking to `<img id="10">` on click. If you don't want that for what you need the `<a>`?